# Python String strip for new lines on a twitter feed

Tags: python, string, twitter

I have a twitter text like this 
what i am trying is to trim all new lines and make it a single string

Text is-------------> RT @KajuBadamChor: Who are we?.
Indian.

what do we wan't?

American Visa.

Why do we wan't it?.

we wanna work for naughty America.

But why?

Because YPD2.

Expecting

Text is-------------> RT @KajuBadamChor: Who are we?.Indian.what do we wan't?American Visa.Why do we wan't it?.we wanna work for naughty America.But why?Because YPD2.

i have tried var[i]['text'].rstrip("\n")

that is right strip for new line characters but it doesn't seems to be giving the o/p i expect , i have been coding python for last few days hence i am sure i am missing something very simple , Help please , suggestions willd o , not expecting you to give me a code solution :)

Thanks

Comment: Try : `var[i]['text'] = var[i]['text'].rstrip("\n")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var[i]['text'] = var[i]['text'].replace('\n', '')
```